# No response in loadFile Dropbox SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I'm calling to loadFile in main thread and SOMETIMES my application is hang. Not crash and not call any callback I have implemented (loadedFile and loadedFileFailedWithErrors). Any limitations? Any other aspect I'm not considering? This is the call

```
   [self.restClient loadFile:filename intoPath:filePath];
```

Comment: check progress in the delegate method. is it still running?

Comment: @Andrey Chernuka you mean in [loadProgress:progress, destPath]? never called ... I have implemented only printing PRETTY_FUNCTION

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that might cause your delegate methods to not be called:

1. Your rest client is nil or is being released (e.g., by ARC) prematurely.
2. You're making the call in a background thread that doesn't have a run loop.
3. Your delegate method that should be called back has a typo in it. Unfortunately the SDK doesn't warn you if it can't find a delegate method to call; it just completes without telling anyone.